# Delphi: Some tip to parse this html table?

Tags: html, delphi, html-parsing

some time I'm trying to get data from this html table, I tried components paid and free. I tried to do some coding and also got no results. I have a class that throw directly html tables for ClientDataSet, but with this table it does not work. Anyone have any tips on how to get the data in this html table? Or a way to convert it to txt / xls / csv or xml? Follows the code for the table:

```
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://site2.aesa.pb.gov.br/aesa/monitoramentoPluviometria.do?metodo=listarMesesChuvasMensais');
  WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.All.Tags('select').Item(0).Value:= '2013';
  WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.All.Tags('select').Item(1).Value:= '7';
  WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.All.Tags('input').Item(1).click;
  Memo1.Text:= WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.All.Tags('table').Item(10).InnerHTML;
  Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('table.html');
```

Comment: Use an html parser. No neeb for a web broswer control because you are not interested in displaying the website. Download html using indy or similar, and then parse it.

Comment: Do you have some example with Indy? I've tried with DIHtmlParser, CleverComponents, 'SMImport', my own code ... and so on. I do not know much working with html, this should be the problem.

Comment: There are countless examples on the web. You can do that sort of research for yourself quite easily. Indy isn't an html parser of course.

Comment: Ok, one more week...Indy is my last chance.

Comment: It sounds to me as though you are attempting a task that is a little beyond your expertise level. Maybe you should break it down. First of all be able to download the html. Then work out how to parse it. Delphi probably not the simplest way to do this.

Comment: The problem with "screen-scraping" data from html web pages is that it makes your app very brittle - if the page's layout gets changed, it will likely break your app.  Better still, you get no advance notice that it's changing, so the first you tend to hear is from irate users.  If this is weather data from a government department, it's worthwhile at least asking them whether you can get the data in a less app-hostile format like xml.

Comment: Btw, while @David Heffernan's advice is always good, in this case, you might do better to stick with TWebBrowser, seeing as you're already using its DOM to simulate a click on the page's button, and IE's DOM Parser is very quick and robust, ime, and handles js-generated tags.  If you are already somewhat familiar with it, you might do better sticking with it than face a possibly-steep learning curve, and possibly in a hurry, by the sound of it.

Comment: Probably @DavidHeffernan, I'm an environmental engineer, I studied during my education a few programming languages ​​(Pascal, Matlab, R, fortran, etc.), no OOP or web-languages​​. It's been less than two months that I devote myself to the object pascal.

Comment: @MartynA I'm exactly trying to get this data from a government site for undergraduates and graduate students can use for research, although Brazil has a law of free access to government data, especially that provide inputs to generate products for society, the law is not enforced. Are data on water resources which can help make modeling and avoid problems related to droughts.

Comment: Do you have to use that particular site?  google finds a number with historical weather data for Brazil in XML and JSON format.

Comment: Yes I put the site [link](http://site2.aesa.pb.gov.br/aesa/monitoramentoPluviometria.do?metodo=listarMesesChuvasMensais) in question above, is a static table. I can now navigate through it by delphi and extract the pages and the table I want in html. It now remains to extract the data and pass it to xml, csv, ClientDataSets, etc.

Comment: @Artur_Indio This sort of task is much more suited to a scripting language. I'd always choose Python (or indeed others if you prefer) over Delphi which is, in my view, absolutely the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: @David, it is trivial, even e.g. with MSHTML. You just find that table element and break it through `IHTMLTable` interface. That's all. No need for browser. No need for scripting language.

Comment: @TLama It's easier in a language like Python with the excellent libraries that are available. It's a much more productive environment for tasks like this. Always using the same tool for all tasks is a mistake.

Comment: Search for DIHtmlParser component. It is one I've used in the past. It makes tasks like this much easier. Here's a free one: https://code.google.com/p/ljbvcltools/source/browse/trunk/HTMLParser/HTMLParser.pas?r=4

Comment: Thanks for all guys! I will take a look in all aproachs. @DavidHeffernan but can i integrate python in my delphi program?

Comment: If you have to do it in Delphi, so be it. I'm supposing you have free tool choice.

Comment: Ok, free choices are my quest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will extract the data from the HTML table on your target page
and load it into a ClientDataSet.

It's fairly long-winded, perhaps demonstrating that as David said, Delphi
is maybe not the best tool for the job.

On my Form1, I have a TEdit, edValue, for me to key in the value in the first
data row in the HTML table data.  I use this as a way to find the table in the
HTML document.  I dare say there are better methods, but at least my method should be more robust than hard-coding assumptions about the layout of the document in which the table is embedded that maybe won't survive a change by the page's author.

Broadly, the code works by first finding the HTML table cell using the contents of
my edValue.Text, then finding the table to which the cell belongs, and then
populating the CDS's Fields and data from the table.

The CDS fields are set to 255 characters by default; maybe there's a specification for
the data published on the web page that would allow you to use a smaller value for some, if not all, fields.  They're all assumed to be of type ftString, to avoid the code choking on unexpected cell contents.

Btw, at the bottom is a utility function for saving the HTML page locally, to
save having to keep clicking the button for selecting a year + month.  To reload
the WebBrowser from the saved file, just use the file's name as the URL to load.

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
[ ... ]
public
  { Public declarations }
  Doc : IHtmlDocument2;

procedure TForm1.btnFindValueClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Table : IHTMLTable;
begin
  Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  Table := FindTableByCellValue(edValue.Text);
  Assert(Table <> Nil);
  LoadCDSFromHTMLTable(CDS, Table);
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadCDSFromHTMLTable(DestCDS : TClientDataSet; Table : IHTMLTable);
var
  I,
  J : Integer;
  vTable : OleVariant;
  iRow : IHTMLTableRow;
  FieldName,
  FieldValue : String;
  Field : TField;
const
  cMaxFieldSize = 255;
  scIDFieldName = 'ID';
begin
  //  Use OleVariant instead of IHTMLTable becuse it's less fiddly for doing what follows
  vTable := Table;
  Assert(not DestCDS.Active and (DestCDS.FieldCount = 0));

  //  First create an AutoInc field
  Field := TAutoIncField.Create(Self);
  Field.FieldName := scIDFieldName;
  Field.DataSet := DestCDS;


  // Next create CDS fields from the names in the cells in the first row of the table
  for I := 0 to (vTable.Rows.Item(0).Cells.Length - 1) do begin
    FieldName := vTable.Rows.Item(0).Cells.Item(I).InnerText;
    Field := TStringField.Create(Self);
    // At this point, we might want to clean up the FieldName by removing embedded spaces, etc
    Field.FieldName := FieldName;
    Field.Size := cMaxFieldSize;
    Field.DataSet := DestCDS;
  end;

  DestCDS.DisableControls;
  try
    DestCDS.IndexFieldNames := scIDFieldName;
    DestCDS.CreateDataSet;

    //  Next load the HTML table data into the CDS
    for I := 1 to (vTable.Rows.Length - 1) do begin
      DestCDS.Insert;
      for J := 0 to vTable.Rows.Item(0).Cells.Length - 1 do begin
        FieldValue := vTable.Rows.Item(I).Cells.Item(J).InnerText;
        // the J + 1 is because Fields[0] is the autoinc one
        DestCDS.Fields[J + 1].AsString := FieldValue;
      end;
      DestCDS.Post;
    end;
    DestCDS.First;
  finally
    DestCDS.EnableControls;
  end;
end;

function TForm1.FindTableCellByTagValue(Doc : IHtmlDocument2; const AValue : String) : IHTMLTableCell;
var
  All: IHTMLElementCollection;
  Value: String;
  I,
  Len: Integer;
  E: OleVariant;
  iE : IHTMLElement;
  iT : IHTMLTextElement;
  iC : IHTMLTableCell;
begin
  Result := Nil;
  All := Doc.All;
  if All = Nil then Exit;
  Len := All.Length;

  for I := 0 to Len - 1 do begin
    E := All.Item(I, varEmpty);
    iE := IDispatch(E) as IHTMLElement;
    if Supports(iE, IHTMLTableCell, iC) then begin
      Value := Trim(iE.Get_InnerText);
      if Pos(Trim(AValue), Value) = 1 then begin
        Result := iC;
        Break;
      end
    end
    else
      Continue;
  end;
end;

function TForm1.FindTableByCellValue(Value : String): IHTMLTable;
var
  Node : IHtmlElement;
  iTable : IHTMLTable;
  iCell : IHTMLTableCell;
begin
  Result := Nil;
  iCell := FindTableCellByTagValue(Doc, edValue.Text);
  if iCell = Nil then
    Exit;
  Node := IDispatch(iCell) as IHtmlElement;

  //  if we found a Node with the cell text we were looking for,
  //  we can now find the HTML table to which it belongs

  while Node <> Nil do begin
    Node := Node.parentElement;
    if Supports(Node, IHTMLTable, iTable) then begin
      Result := iTable;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SaveFileLocally(const FileName : String);
var
  PFile: IPersistFile;  // declared in ActiveX unit
begin
  PFile := Doc as IPersistFile;
  PFile.Save(StringToOleStr(FileName), False);
end;
```

Comment: Hello, wow! Many thanks for this. Guy had just posted my answer, and when I saw your page updated, wow what your work! It does not compare to mine, thanks again. Actually the job is onerous but I have to do in Delphi, I am now trying by MSHTML and this code will help a lot. I'll have a lot of work yet because I want to loop through each pages (there are five) each year and each month, and then put on the CD...

Comment: ...With your help and that of colleagues in the comments above, I opened my mind a little more and overcome the challenges. Many thanks again for onerous code, it will help me a lot and also other people(who need examples).

Answer (score 1):

after some time studying I finally extract data from html table. To simplify I can extract data from html table directly, without having to 'parse' it was the tag 'table' and 'item' 11 the 'item' 10 had the same data but in a single cell. So what I did, I took each element of the table in html and StringGrid filled one, and then found a way to directly populate the dbgrid through ClientDataSet. I'll post the code (unit) to stand as an example and for that you need someone. I wanted to thank everyone who helped me in the comments. With more study'm seeing that the best way to do this procedure is to MSHTML.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.OleCtrls, SHDocVw, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids, Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    ClientDataSet1MunicípioPosto: TStringField;
    ClientDataSet1TotalMensalmm: TStringField;
    ClientDataSet1ClimatologiaMensalmm: TStringField;
    ClientDataSet1Desviomm: TStringField;
    ClientDataSet1Desvio: TStringField;
    ClientDataSet1id: TAutoIncField;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 irow, jcol: Integer;
 ovTable: OleVariant;
begin

 ovTable := WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.tags('table').item(11);
 ShowMessage('Number of Rows: '+IntToStr(ovTable.Rows.Length));
 ShowMessage('Number of Cols: '+IntToStr(ovTable.Rows.Item(0).Cells.Length));
 StringGrid1.RowCount:= ovTable.Rows.Length+1;
 StringGrid1.ColCount:= ovTable.Rows.Item(0).Cells.Length+1;
 for irow := 0 to (ovTable.Rows.Length - 1) do
 begin
   for jcol := 0 to (ovTable.Rows.Item(irow).Cells.Length - 1) do
   begin
     StringGrid1.Cells[jcol+1, irow+1] := ovTable.Rows.Item(irow).Cells.Item(jcol).InnerText;
   end;
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

var
iRow : Integer;
iCol : Integer;
ovTable: OleVariant;

begin
  ovTable := WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.tags('table').item(11);
  for iRow := 1 to (ovTable.Rows.Length - 1) do
    begin
      ClientDataSet1.Open;
      ClientDataSet1.insert;
      for iCol := 0 to (ovTable.Rows.Item(iRow).Cells.Length - 1) do
      begin
      ClientDataSet1.FieldByname('Município/Posto').AsString:=ovTable.Rows.Item(iRow).Cells.Item(0).InnerText;
      ClientDataSet1.FieldByname('Total Mensal (mm)').AsString:=ovTable.Rows.Item(iRow).Cells.Item(1).InnerText;
      ClientDataSet1.FieldByname('Climatologia Mensal (mm)').AsString:=ovTable.Rows.Item(iRow).Cells.Item(2).InnerText;
      ClientDataSet1.FieldByname('Desvio (mm)').AsString:=ovTable.Rows.Item(iRow).Cells.Item(3).InnerText;
      ClientDataSet1.FieldByname('Desvio (%)').AsString:=ovTable.Rows.Item(iRow).Cells.Item(4).InnerText;

      end;
      ClientDataSet1.Post;
      ClientDataSet1.IndexFieldNames:= 'id';
      ClientDataSet1.First;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('C:\htmlwiththetable.html');
end;

end
```

.

Comment: Glad you're making progress.  Just one minor thing: re-arrange your FormClose so that Application.Terminate is the last thing you call - although it would be better to remove it entirely, because if Form1 is the main form in your project, closing it will terminate your application anyway.

Comment: It's true. I was writing a code on FormClose and then let it go, I will fix this, thanks.