# Efficient Delphi method to parse HTML code for data

Tags: html, parsing, delphi

I sometimes need to parse data like these:

```
<tr>
  <td data-th="Name">
    John Smith
  </td>
  <td data-th="Phone">
    1234567
  </td>
  <td data-th="Postal">
    16803
  </td>
  <td data-th="Office Number">
    12345678
  </td>
  <td data-th="Remarks">
    Hello
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td data-th="Name">
    Mary Smith
  </td>
  <td data-th="Phone">
    1234589
  </td>
  <td data-th="Postal">
    16801
  </td>
  <td data-th="Office Number">
    2385234
  </td>
  <td data-th="Remarks">
    Hi There
  </td>
</tr>
```

I would do something like loading this to a `TStringList`:

```
for i := 0 to oStringList.Count-1 do
begin
  if oStringList[i].Trim = '<tr>' then
  begin
    // start of record
  end else if oStringList[i].Trim = '</tr>' then
  begin 
    // end of record
  end else
  begin
    // part of record data
  end;
end;
```

Is there a better way to do this, either via some very efficient code, or is there already some really good Delphi components (preferably free/opensource) that can accomplish this?  I saw a thread (dated 3+ years ago) in stackoverflow that mentioned a component, just wondering if something better has popped up.

Thanks.

Update: trying the htmlp component -->  how do I configure the code to parse above data... the sketchy example did not help.  i want to loop through each TR/TR and get the

```
  var HtmlParser: THtmlParser;
  var  HtmlDoc: TDocument;
  var  x: Integer;
  var  body, el: TElement;
  var  node: TNode;
  begin
    HtmlParser := THtmlParser.Create;
    try
      HtmlDoc := HtmlParser.parseString(memo1.Text);
      try
        body := GetDocBody(HtmlDoc);
        if Assigned(body) then
        for x := 0 to body.childNodes.length - 1 do
        begin
          node := body.childNodes.item(x);
          if (node is TElement) then
          begin
            el := node as TElement;
            if (el.tagName = 'td') then //and (el.GetAttribute('data-th') = 'Name') then
            begin
              // iterate el.childNodes here...
              //ShowMessage(IntToStr(el.childNodes.length));
              memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(el.childNodes.length));
            end else
            begin

            end;
          end else
          begin
            memo1.Lines.Add('node is not element');
          end;
        end;
      finally
        HtmlDoc.Free;
      end;
    finally
      HtmlParser.Free
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: "Is there a better way to do this[?]" Yes, use an HTML parser. We cannot recommend one, though, since software recommendation is explicitly disallowed by Stack Overflow rules.

Comment: Then may I ask if htmlp is a very good choice, since you cannot recommend?

Comment: Do not expect HTML to come in multiple lines - stuffing everything together without one single linebreak is legal. A (HTML) parser will most likely choke on syntax/logic errors (such as your 2 `</td>` in a row) that could be easy for you as a human to adapt to, but on the other hand it also most likely supports entities (`&lt;`) and whatnot that must be expected with HTML.

Comment: That's true. I have corrected the double `</td>`.  may i ask if anyone has any experience with the htmlp parser to know how to parse in this case?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24851358/2663863) for extracting data from an html table to a dataset component.

Comment: Why do you need to parse HTML in the first place?

Comment: who is "THtmlParser" ?

Answer (score 1):

When it is well formed HTML like that, where start entries also have end entries (`<TR>...</TR>`) then it is basically XML. So you can use an XML reader to parse the document.

Using kbmMW's XML parser like this:

```
const
  HTML =
'  <tr>'+
'  <td data-th="Name">'+
'    John Smith'+
'  </td>'+
'  <td data-th="Phone">'+
'    1234567'+
'  </td>'+
'  <td data-th="Postal">'+
'    16803'+
'  </td>'+
'  <td data-th="Office Number">'+
'    12345678'+
'  </td>'+
'  <td data-th="Remarks">'+
'    Hello'+
'  </td>'+
'</tr>'+
'<tr>'+
'  <td data-th="Name">'+
'    Mary Smith'+
'  </td>'+
'  <td data-th="Phone">'+
'    1234589'+
'  </td>'+
'  <td data-th="Postal">'+
'    16801'+
'  </td>'+
'  <td data-th="Office Number">'+
'    2385234'+
'  </td>'+
'  <td data-th="Remarks">'+
'    Hi There'+
'  </td>'+
'</tr>';
    
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   xml:TkbmMWDOMXML;
   i,j:integer;
   nTR,nTD:TkbmMWDOMXMLNodeList;
   n1,n2:TkbmMWDOMXMLNode;
begin
     Memo1.Clear;
     xml:=TkbmMWDOMXML.Create(HTML);
     try
        nTR:=xml.Root.ChildrenByName['tr'];
        try
           for i:=0 to nTR.Count-1 do
           begin
                n1:=nTR.Nodes[i];
                nTD:=n1.ChildrenByName['td'];
                try
                   for j:=0 to nTD.Count-1 do
                   begin
                        n2:=nTD.Nodes[j];
                        Memo1.Lines.Add(n2.AttribByName['data-th']+'='+n2.Data);
                   end;
                finally
                   nTD.Free;
                end;
           end;
        finally
           nTR.Free;
        end;
     finally
        xml.Free;
     end;
end;
```

Results in this:

```
Name=John Smith
Phone=1234567
Postal=16803
Office Number=12345678
Remarks=Hello
Name=Mary Smith
Phone=1234589
Postal=16801
Office Number=2385234
Remarks=Hi There
```

The kbmMW XML parser is included, along with much much more, in the free Community Edition that can be downloaded from https://portal.components4developers.com after registering.

Comment: Isn't html that is also xml known as xhtml

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Definitly yes. HTML is SGML, so only the "ML" part is the most common denominator. HTML5 should be impossible to parse as XML because [missing closing tags are legal now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#XHTML_5_(XML-serialized_HTML_5)), so this answer implies HTML2 thru 4 or XHTML1.

Comment: @peter There are many XML parsers available, and many of them have more permissive licences than Kim's parser that he is promoting here. Indeed the standard Delphi libraries have a fully functional XML parser that should be more than enough to meet your needs.

Comment: @KimMadsen my apologies the other day when I saw your answer, the site was going under maintenance so I was not able to accept the answer as correct.

Comment: @AmigoJack thanks for your reply

Comment: @DavidHeffernan do you have a link to an example of this xml parser? the one I saw was tied to the webbrowser's DOM.

Comment: You can find examples with websearch